# Updating Azure Table Entities using the C# API without overwriting value types

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'm trying to use the C# Azure Table API to update a property in table storage by creating a brand new entity and merging it:

```
// Create an object that only specifies the property to update
// (null properties are not updated)
var itemToUpdate = new TableEntity("PartitionKey", "RowKey");
itemToUpdate.DateLastAccessedUtc = DateTime.Now;
// can't do this!          
//itemToUpdate.DateCreatedUtc = null;

// Attach to the item, update it, and save the changes
_dataContext.AttachTo(_dataContext.TableName, itemToUpdate, "*");
_dataContext.UpdateObject(itemToUpdate);
_dataContext.SaveChanges();
```

Basically, I want to update the last accessed date without updating the created date, but since DateTimes cannot be null, I can't do it.  Is it possible to do this without making two calls to the table?  Since this will be called frequently, I don't want to retrieve the object before updating it if I can avoid it.

Comment: Can you set DateCreated back to itself?

Comment: Since I'm trying to update the object without retrieving it first from table storage, I don't have a value to set it to.  When I create a new TableEntity, the DateCreated field just gets set to the default DateTime value.  So, unfortunately, I can't :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is true that a `DateTime` itself can't be null, if you use a `Nullable<DateTime>` (or `DateTime?` if you prefer) instead then you are able to set that date to null (and the Storage Client Library understands what to do with `Nullable<>` types.  This may not make sense for the other places you're using this object though.

If using a nullable type doesn't make sense for that you could try this alternate idea (I'm not sure how sensible this is, but I think it will do what you want).  Create a new class `TableEntityJustLastAccessed` which has the usual `PartitionKey`/`RowKey`/`Timestamp` properties plus just the `DateLastAccessedUtc` property that you want to update.

In your update code, rather than creating a `TableEntity`, create a `TableEntityJustLastAccessed` with the same `PartitionKey`/`RowKey` and save that.  Because by default the storage client library merges changes rather than override the whole object, it should update just the property you care about.

Comment: These are both good solutions.  Since the second solution makes it more difficult to extend the property list, I ended up going with using Nullable types, which worked like a charm.  Thanks!